# ¿Como obtener el porcentaje de una cantidad de registros del total de registros en una tabla en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Este es mi query con el cual calculo cual es la cantidad de registros entre una fecha y otra y es parte de mi solución pero que tal si quisiera obtener el porcentaje de dicha cantidad de registros por supuesto del total de registros de dicha tabla

```
SELECT  count(id) as Total FROM usuarios
WHERE fechaRegistro BETWEEN '2020-06-02 12:52:52' AND '2020-06-05 12:52:52'
ORDER BY fechaRegistro
```

Comment: Pues, puedes obtener el count de los registros totales de la tabla antes con `Declare @TotalRegistros int =(Select count(*) from Usuarios)`. Luego divides el resultado de tu consulta entre `@TotalRegistros` y lo multiplicas por 100?